# Excel VBA protecting calculation from dividing by 0

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate cells with data based on a simple division but there are (and will always be) instances where I have a 0 on one or both ends of the equation.

Is it possible to wrap some kind of protection around the equation so that if it's a division by 0 it just sets the value to 0 rather then error out?

My code

```
Set myRange = Range("S3:S20")
rowCounter = 3
For Each myCell In myRange
    If Range("H1").Value Like "*Mon*" Then
        myCell.Value = Range("Q" & rowCounter).Value
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

    Else
        myCell.Value = ((myCell.Value + Range("Q" & rowCounter).Value) / Range("R" & rowCounter).Value)
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

    End If
Next myCell
```

Below is the data referenced in the equation

```
P    Q      R    S
5   1:03    5   1:03
0   0:00    0   0:00
0   0:00    0   0:00
7   0:19    7   0:19
0   0:00    0   0:00
0   0:00    0   0:00
12  0:26    12  0:26
3   0:15    3   0:15
3   1:16    3   1:16
7   0:29    7   0:29
9   0:14    9   0:14
0   0:00    0   0:00
0   0:00    0   0:00
6   0:28    6   0:28
0   0:00    0   0:00
4   0:15    4   0:15
0   0:00    0   0:00
0   0:00    0   0:00
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Just insert `ElseIf Range("R" & rowCounter).Value = 0 Then` as an additional condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below (check if the value in Column R = 0).

Since you are looping with `For Each myCell In myRange`, there is no need to have another variable (`rowCounter`)  to keep the row number, just use `myCell.Row`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HandleDev_ByZero()

Dim myRange As Range, myCell As Range

Set myRange = Range("S3:S20")
For Each myCell In myRange
    If Range("H1").Value Like "*Mon*" Then
        myCell.Value = Range("Q" & myCell.Row).Value
    Else
        If Range("R" & myCell.Row).Value = 0 Then ' check if 0
            myCell.Value = 0
        Else
            myCell.Value = ((myCell.Value + Range("Q" & myCell.Row).Value) / Range("R" & myCell.Row).Value)
        End If
    End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice solution. You can also get of `Dim rowCounter as Long`.

Comment: That comment... is a great example of why good comments should say *why*, not *what* - the code says one thing, the comment says another. I'd drop the comment, `If foo = 0 Then` is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 5):

I answer your question along with some other considerations:

- you can exploit `IfError()` `WorksheetFunction` to trap the error
- it's a logical error to repeat `If Range("H1").Value Like "*Mon*" Then` at every iteration

  check it once at the beginning and then proceed accordingly
- you can avoid `counter` variable by offsetting the loop range variable

for all what above you could code

```
Sub main()
    Dim myRange As Range, myCell As Range

    Set myRange = Range("S3:S20")
    If Range("H1").Value Like "*Mon*" Then
        myRange.Value = myRange.Offset(, -2).Value
    Else
        For Each myCell In myRange
            myCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=iferror((" & myCell.Value & "+ RC[-2])/RC[-1],0)"
        Next myCell
        myRange.Value = myRange.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

How about an extra **ElseIF statement** that check for the value in column R:

```
Set myRange = Range("S3:S20")
rowCounter = 3
For Each myCell In myRange
        If Range("H1").Value Like "*Mon*" Then
            myCell.Value = Range("Q" & rowCounter).Value
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        ElseIf Range("R" & rowCounter).Value <> "0" Then
            myCell.Value = ((myCell.Value + Range("Q" & rowCounter).Value) / Range("R" & rowCounter).Value)
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Else
            myCell.Value = 0
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        End If
Next myCell
```